# Please review my schematic for vision processing kit - Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+ and camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, schematics, camera

I'm very new to board design and i want to get a review for my schematic.

I'm making a vision processing kit using a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+ and the Raspberry Pi camera that can be powered using passive PoE or a 12 V input.

There's also an extra USB port to connect external devices and a USB Micro-B so I could flash the Pi. Please tell me if I did everything correctly and if I can improve my design.
Thanks.

[image: schematic]

[schematic as pdf](https://filebin.net/8so04aq7s2ryon3s/Schematic_Chameleon_Box_20200307233423.pdf?t=mrq4jk5n)

Answer (score 1):

- SPI for a network device attached to a computer that has USB2.0 high speed sounds inefficient, slow and unnecessarily complex.
- I don't see any PoE infrastructure there, so you didn't fulfill your design goals.

  - on the contrary, I don't know that ethernet jack, but it seems like you just connected a center tap to power lines. That is almost certainly not what you want if you have a non-standard ("passive") PoE injector, and it won't work with a standards-compliant PoE injector.
- Instead of a USB switch, you should just add a USB hub. It's not actually much harder.
- Don't forget that your MIPI is a high-speed bus and needs to be layouted accordingly.

Aside from the RPi Camera, which seems quite nice, I'm not convinced the compute module is really what you're aiming for: your board offers nothing that wouldn't be on one of the full Raspberry Pis, so safe yourself money and design effort and buy one of these.

Or don't, most embedded engineers don't consider the RPis to be overly fantastic devices [compared](https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-xu4-special-price/) to the rest of the market. Especially for computer vision applications, it looks a bit weak on the CPU, too small in terms of RAM, unsatisfying GPU. Also, lack of ethernet in your application actually looks like a deal-breaker to me.

Comment: so im using the spi Ethernet for 2 reasons.
1. i dont need high bandwidth this device is going to be connected to a closed network
2. i need as much bandwidth for the usb camera that is connected to the usb A port

as for the passive poe i was folowing this schematic https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-qXsn6YVknb8/XAUyj7Z_dfI/AAAAAAAAHVg/iUZQ1ikOwHY1zTRSKfHC5SuhF5l4jFE9QCLcBGAs/s1600/48V%2BPoE%2BInjector%2BDIY.jpg
and the schematic for the jr45 port that i used

Comment: well, if you need high USB throughput, a USB2 host device like the Rpi3 CM is the wrong choice. Also, cameras typically use isochronous mode, so "sharing" the bus doesn't affect their performance as long as the sum rate is sufficient.

Comment: I have to use the raspberry pi.

Comment: hm, that's bad luck. To be honest, your requirements and the things you have to use don't work well together.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: You have a cool application, but the fact that you must use the slow and underequipped RPi3 compute module is an unnecessary obstacle.

Comment: Except the usage of the pi everything else is ok?

Comment: No, that's why the list in my answer has more than one point.

Comment: As I mentioned before the Poe is connected using this schematic https://www.google.com/search?q=passive+poe+schema&client=ms-unknown&prmd=ivsn&sxsrf=ALeKk00rOxUcyqwnZpYzIefLpCh-ST_SlQ:1583669534866&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8x8Tg7IroAhUDSBUIHcI1Du4Q_AUoAXoECA8QAQ#imgrc=O_StSMw_3Z-GHM

Comment: And the use of the usb switch is the same as the raspberry dev board to detect and switch to flash the emmc